# How to get detail sum on parent field xaf

Tags: devexpress, xaf

In a XAF project I use DomainComponent like the following:

```
 [DomainComponent]
 public interface IService
 {
      decimal Amount { get;set; };
 }

 [DomainComponent]
 public interface IEntity
 {
      decimal Total { get;set; }
      IList<IService> Services { get;set; }
 }
```

I want to get detail list's sum into parent Total field after detail list changed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to declare your Total property as follows:

```
[Calculated("Services.Sum(Amount)")]
decimal Total { get; }
```

Alternatively, you can use the BeforeChange_ logic.
Finally, you can add such a calculated field without modifying your interfaces, at the Application Model level as per [this article](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113583).

P.S.
Do not hesitate to contact the DevExpress support team directly if you experience any further difficulties: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create